# Using Looper.prepare in AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am using asyncTask a lot in my project, and sometimes i receive this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
```

The first class that raises problem is:

```
public class GetDetails extends
        AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {

    public String URL = null;
    public Activity context;
    private boolean success = false;
    private String id;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        linlaHeaderProgress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        // Get the application instance
        AppsPlaceApplication.initInstance();
    }

    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... params) {
//      Looper.prepare();

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = null;
        try {
            httppost = new HttpPost(new URI(URL)); 
            List<BasicNameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair>();
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", id));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            httppost.setHeader("Content-type",
                    "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                if (entity != null) {
                    InputStream in = entity.getContent();
                    String result = HelperJsonStatic.convertStreamToString(in);

                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(context, "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } catch (URISyntaxException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

    }
}
```

This is annoying because i don't understand why should i use looper. And if i use that Looper.prepare() line of code, after some time it crashes with another error telling me only one Looper per thread...
Can someone please explain this thing and what i am doing wrong? It's like walking in circle.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are calling `Toast.makeText().show()` from `doInBackground()`. You can't do this because `doInBackground()` is called on a background thread. You should show the `Toast` in `onPostExecute()` instead.

Comment: @user1140656 It will. 100% guarantee. :)